# Display content between squares with links

Tags: 7

I want to build a Drupal 7 website with big squares which contain a title and some text. In a desktop layout there will be 3 rows of 3 squares. Each square is a link to one or more underlaying pages. I am thinking of using the views module to make this work.

After clicking on a square, the content of the underlaying page has to be displayed right under the row of this square. So, if a visitor clicks on a square in the first row, content should be displayed between row 1 and row 2. By clicking on a square in the second row, content should be displayed between row 2 and 3. I have no idea how to do this. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do can be easily accomplished with **JavaScript and CSS**. And. since Drupal already ships with jQuery, you could make use of the [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) effect to slide up and down your content.

**I'll give you a general idea:**

1. In Drupal, create a page that displays your 3 nodes. For example, you could create a View and show the *Title* and *Body* fields of your articles.
2. In your JavaScript, hide the *Body* field by default and then add a *click* event to your *Title* field, so when users click on it, the following *Body* field slides down or up.

   ```
   $('#title-one').click(function() {
       $('#body-one').slideToggle();
   });
   ```

Of course, this is just a starting point and *one* way of doing it. Good luck!